# NilClass error when passing an argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a module that I want to use when sorting out data for displaying in the view. in the terminal, I try the module out like this

```
> include BeforeOrAfter
> s = s.Artist.find(1)
> s.events.each do |event|
>   before_or_after(event)
> end
```

this leads to the error `NoMethodError: undefined method '<<' for nil:NilClass`.
here is my module:

```
module BeforeOrAfter
  attr_reader :past
  attr_reader :future

  require "date"
  def initialize
    @datetime = DateTime.new
    @future = []
    @past = []
  end

  def before_or_after(event)
    if event.date < DateTime.now
      @past << event.id
    else
      @future << event.id
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT: played around more in the console and tried this, and it works. now why doesn't this work when handing everything off to the module to handle?

```
> include BeforeOrAfter
> s = s.Artist.find(1)
> @f = []
> @p = []
> s.events.each do |event|
>   if event.date < DateTime.now
>   @p << event.id
>   else
>     @f << event.id
>   end
> end
> @f
  => [17]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `initialize` method never gets called. You're including the module into the ruby top level object - initialize has already been called.

If you had included it in a more "normal" class, ie

```
class Foo
  include BeforeOrAfter
end
```

The `before_or_after` method should work on instances of Foo

When including in other classes you don't control, you can't guarantee initialise will be called either since that class might define an initailize method of its own. You could `prepend` your module instead of using include to ensure your `initialize` is called first. If you do this make sure you still call the original `initialize` (with `super`) and that your initialize takes the same arguments as the original.

I'd probably initialize your 2 instance variables when they are needed instead of trying to hook into initialize.

Comment: I've had it included in the application_controller, because all the controllers I currently have need it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine changing `attr_reader :past` to `attr_accessor :past` would do it.

Comment: The base implementation you have here seems to work for me in IRB.  I include it into an object, feed an OpenStruct with a date attribute defined into it and it throws no errors.  So yeah, my initial answer is probably incorrect :)  

When I fed the obj.before_or_after an OpenStruct with no date defined however, it did return a `NoMethodError: undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass` error.  I realize you reported your error as having '<<', just double-checking this isn't the same problem.  If so, then you might want to check your event objects and ensure they have a date attribute.

Comment: if I take the `.date` out and make it `if event < DateTime.now`, then it breaks at that line with `<` instead of `<<`, so that should indicate that rails is finding the date attribute?

Comment: I added some more info in the OP